# validate data in an array

Tags: cakephp, validation

Can the `validates` method validate user-defined arrays? for example:

*Model:*

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Recipe extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'price' => 'numeric'
    );
}
```

*And in Controller:*

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class RecipesController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post') && $this->request->data){
            $data = array('price' => $this->request->data['myprice']);
            $this->Reservation->validates($data); //validate the $data array
        }
        else{
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for manually validate you should try this :

```
$this->Reservation->set( $data);
if($this->Reservation->validates(){
 //your code
}else{ 
    $this->validateErrors($this->Reservation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can work with a fieldlist like this:

```
            if ($this->Model->validates(array(
                    'fieldList' => array(
                        'reason',
                        'name',
                        'message',
                    )
                ))) {

                }
```

Hope thats what youre looking for.